# Runtime error '28': Out of stack space in Excel VBA and Excel crashes

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to run the code and build a connection but when I am trying to insert data into a MySQL Database from Excel using VBA. It shows '28: Out of Stack space'

I have a code and this is the data here

```
Name     Analyst     Method    Numsample   Condition
AAA       AAA        AAA         2           ABC
```

Below is the code I have written,

```vb
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()

   On Error GoTo ErrHandle

   Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=******************t-1.rds.amazonaws.com;" & _
        "DATABASE=worksheet;" & _
        "USER=***;" & _
        "PASSWORD=****;" & _
        "Option=3"

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    ConnectDB
    With wsBooks
        For rowCursor = 2 To 3
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestExperiment (Experiment_Name, Experiment_Method, Experiment_Analyst, Experiment_NumSample, Experiment_condition) " & _
                "VALUES ('" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 1)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 2)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 3)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 4)) & "', " & _
                esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 5)) & ")"
            rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Connection successful"

ExitHandle:
   Set con = Nothing  ' RELEASE ALL set OBJECTS
   Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
   MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
   Resume ExitHandle
    End Sub

Function esc(txt As String)
    esc = Trim(Replace(txt, "'", "\'"))
End Function
```

Completely new to VBA, just learning code might have some errors. Please help me if you can thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to insert data, and not return a recordset, try `oConn.Execute strSQL` instead of `rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`. Not sure if you even need a recordset here.

Comment: You are calling ConnectDB from within ConnectDB.

Comment: Line 16, or near there

Comment: @RBarryYoung That solved the issue. Such a silly error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Out of stack space" is VBA's `StackOverflowException`. It means you have inadvertently written recursive logic that never escapes the recursion, keeps digging, and digging deeper, ....until the *call stack* is completely filled and VBA can't track where to return anymore.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    ConnectDB '<~ recursive call!
    With wsBooks
```

Remove the recursive call, problem solved!